# Firebase GeoFire Swift - save coordinates with radius

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have an app where a host of an event could publish an event to people in specific area. For example, he could make an event in some coordinates in New York and says that all people that are 50km around this place could see it.

My question, is it possible to use GeoFire to do this? 
I know that you could use GeoFire to look for events in specific location with radius, but could you do it the other way around (store location with radius and than search for events in your location).

Comment: GeoFire can be used to store the location of keys and then perform geoqueries on them. There is no definition of the meaning of the keys, so you can use them to identify anything you want. If you're having trouble making this work for your use-case, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).